# Django admin list_display newline

Tags: django, django-admin

I try to display text with newlines in list display of admin side of Django.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('example')

def example(self,obj):
    return 'TYPE : %s \n RATE : %s \n FAMILY %s'
```

However, it is displayed without newlines like `TYPE : xxx RATE : yyy FAMILY zzz`.

How can I do this in Django admin ?

Comment: The Django admin is a website. How do you display line breaks in HTML?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to use br instead of a `\n`, and specify that this field is allowed to use html tags:

```
def example(self):
    return 'TYPE : %s<br>RATE : %s<br>FAMILY %s' % (self.type, 
                                                    self.rate, 
                                                    self.family)
example.allow_tags = True
```

Or you can use some more elegant HTML way of formatting your output (like wrapping each in a span element with a certain class, and add some css to make then render below each other).

Answer (score 10):

In Django 2/3, you should use `format_html`, since `allow_tags` has been deprecated.  So, the example code becomes:

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('example',)

    def example(self, obj):
        return format_html('TYPE : %s<br />RATE : %s<br />FAMILY %s' % (
            self.type, self.rate, self.family))
```

Comment: Please [edit] and actually use `format_html` properly, currently you are simply using string formatting and this might introduce an XSS vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use br instead of a \n, and specify that this field is allowed to use html tags:

def example(self):
return 'TYPE : %s
RATE : %s
FAMILY %s' % (self.type,
self.rate,
self.family)
example.allow_tags = True
Or you can use some more elegant HTML way of formatting your output (like wrapping each in a span element with a certain class, and add some css to make then render below each other).