# How to display values in multiple lines by indentation in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, admin, indentation

I have **`Person` model** below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Then, I put `\n` between `obj.first_name` and `obj.last_name` as shown below to display first name and last name separately in 2 lines by indentation:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('person',)
                               
    def person(self, obj):     # ↓↓ Here
        return obj.first_name + "\n" + obj.last_name
```

But, first name and last name were displayed in one line without indentation as shown below:

[image]

```
John Smith # One line
```

So, how can I display first name and last name separately in 2 lines by indentation as shown below:

```
John # 1st line
Smith # 2nd line
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django admin list\_display newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772405/django-admin-list-display-newline)

Answer (score 0):

Add `person()` inside your model:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
    def person(self): # Here
        return mark_safe(self.first_name + '<br>' + self.last_name)
```

Then, put `'person'` to `list_display`:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('person',) # Here
```

Comment: Improper use of `mark_safe` can be dangerous. In this particular case the first name / last name fields can potentially be used to perform XSS attacks. You should either use [escape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.escape) on the first / last names or use the [format_html](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [format_html()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) which is recommended in the documentation instead of [mark_safe()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) and you should use `"<br/>"` instead of `"\n"` as shown below. *In [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html), why to use `format_html()` instead of `mark_safe()` is explained:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person
from django.utils.html import format_html

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('person',)
                               
    def person(self, obj):  # ↓↓↓↓↓ Replaced with "\n"
        return format_html("{}<br/>{}", obj.first_name, obj.last_name)
               # ↑ Here
```

Then, you can display first name and last name separately in 2 lines by indentation as shown below:

[image]